# Test class for StandardSetController - 'Constructor not defined' error

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a test class for my StandardSetController and the error that is being returned is 'Constructor is not defined' for this line: 'opportunityList2Con ext = new opportunityList2Con(stdSetController)'.

```
@isTest

public class opportunityList2ConTestClass {



    public static final Id oppNBRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('New Business - Read Only').getRecordTypeId();

    /* Create User record */

    public static User u = TestHelper.createAdminUser('abc@xyz.com'); 

    /* Create Account record */

    public static Account a = TestHelper.createAccount(u.Id, 'Account Name - InfoYTD'); 



    public static testMethod void testOppCreation() {



        // List of Opportunities

        List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();



        oppList.add(new Opportunity(

            AccountId = a.Id, OwnerId = u.Id, StageName = 'Closed Won', 

            RecordTypeId = oppNBRecordTypeId, Name = 'Opportunity NB A Test', CurrencyIsoCode = 'GBP',

            Amount = 1000, Billing_Effective_Date__c = date.today(), CloseDate = date.today()));



        oppList.add(new Opportunity(

            AccountId = a.Id, OwnerId = u.Id, StageName = 'Closed Won', 

            RecordTypeId = oppNBRecordTypeId, Name = 'Opportunity NB A Test', CurrencyIsoCode = 'GBP',

            Amount = 2000, Billing_Effective_Date__c = date.today(), CloseDate = date.today()));



        insert oppList;



        Test.startTest();



        PageReference testPage = new PageReference('/apex/opportunityList2ConVFPage');

        Test.setCurrentPage(testPage);

                        ApexPages.StandardSetController stdSetController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(oppList);

                        opportunityList2Con ext = new opportunityList2Con(stdSetController);



        Test.stopTest();



    }
```

The extension class (condensed to show the main logic) is:

```
public with sharing class opportunityList2Con extends NBClosedWonYTD {

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {        
        get {
            if(setCon == null) { 

        /* Record Type Id */        
        String recordTypeIdValue = ''; 
        recordTypeIdValue = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pv0');
        Id recordTypeIdX = Id.valueOf(recordTypeIdValue);          

        /* Calendar Months for Billing Effective Date */        
        String nb1 = '';  
        nb1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pv1');
        Integer monthValue1 = Integer.valueOf(nb1);

        setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Name, IsWon, convertCurrency(Amount), Owner_Region__c, CloseDate, Billing_Effective_Date__c, Owner.Name, Account.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName =:stages AND Billing_Effective_Date__c = THIS_YEAR AND RecordType.Id =: recordTypeIdX AND (CALENDAR_MONTH(Billing_Effective_Date__c) =: monthValue1 ORDER BY Billing_Effective_Date__c]));

            }
            return setCon;
        } 
        set; 
    } 

    public List<Opportunity> getOpportunitiesWon() {
         setCon.setPageSize(setCon.getResultSize()); 
         return (List<Opportunity>) setCon.getRecords();
    }

    }
```

Can someone please advise me why this error is being returned and how I can rectify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test assumes your extension class has this constructor (that it doesn't have):

```
public with sharing class opportunityList2Con extends NBClosedWonYTD {

    public opportunityList2Con(ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon) {
        this.setCon = setCon;
    }

    ...
}
```

But your extension class seems designed to create its own `StandardSetController` based on parameters called "pv0" and "pv1". So probably best to change your test to supply those parameters and just use the default constructor:

```
testPage.getParameters().put('pv0', ...);
testPage.getParameters().put('pv1', ...);
Test.setCurrentPage(testPage);

opportunityList2Con ext = new opportunityList2Con();
System.assertNotEquals(null, ext.setCon);
...
```

(You haven't posted the `NBClosedWonYTD` class or the page this extension is used in; they would both potentially influence the answer here.)